# Where to add google analytics script code in magento2 file path?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

I don't know how to implement this task. I have to add google analytics code but where to add file path I don't know. Can you please tell me the file path in magento2?

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in to your Magento 2 admin and go to Stores > Configuration.
2. Then go to Sales -> Google API -> Google Analytics.
3. Enable -> Yes, Add your tracking number in "Account Number" and Save Config
4. Flush Cache

Comment: Hi @Evince Development, I want to add bing script code for adding bing search engine to my magento2 website then where to add that script code in Magento2

Comment: For all the pages?

Comment: Only for checkout pages.

Comment: Do you mean only on the checkout success page? Can you please post a new question for this?

Comment: Hi @Evince Development, I want to add Google tag manager script code for magento2 file path? I don't know the file path for magento2. Could you please help me?

Comment: Please post the new question for this.

Comment: Hi @Evince Development, I already posted the new question please find this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243417/where-to-add-google-tag-manager-script-code-for-magento2-file-path