# Magento 2 -Google Tag Manager Enhanced E-commerce Tracking?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

How to add Google tag manager Enhanced E-commerce tracking in magento2? 
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

For Advanced Ecommerece tracking you can use [weltpixel](https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html), a free extension.

**NOTE** : just so you know this extension will update some of templates ( i.e product / category listing page )

Comment: Does This extension support Enhanced E commerce Tracking?

Comment: @Sanjay Gohil, it does but i guess it needs some keyworkd mapping / configurations etc.

Comment: I got your point Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As specified by @Amex above, you can add basic script of GTM code on your Magento 2 store but GTM is all about data and data layers without them there is very little can be done using the basic script of GTM.

For example - for Google Enhanced Ecommerce, you need to create data layers for all the below actions / pages

- Product Impressions (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions
- Product Clicks (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-clicks
- Product Detail Impressions (for product detail page) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#details
- Add / Remove from Cart (for add to cart or remove from cart action) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#cart
- Promotion Impressions (for list of banners / ads) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#promo-impressions
- Promotion Clicks (for click of the banner / ad image) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#promo-clicks
- Checkout (for checkout / checkout steps) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout
- Purchases (for order confirmation page) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases
- Refunds (from admin to send refund to GA in case of refunds) https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#refunds

If you are a developer you can add the above data layers in your code using the following layout handlers -:

- default.xml
- catalog_category_view.xml
- catalog_product_view.xml
- catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml
- catalogsearch_result_index.xml
- checkout_cart_index.xml
- checkout_index_index.xml
- checkout_onepage_success.xml

If not then there are quite few extensions available for small amount to buy. Personally I would recommend the following two extension for M1 and M2

[M1 Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html)

[M2 Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html)

Answer (score 0):

What You need is to add the [GTM code](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) to your active theme. 
The GTM code have two parts: script and noscript.

Make sure a nonscript part comes just after openning of `<body>` tag otherwise the `dataLayer` will not work
make two files:

> I.   gtm_head.phtml ---> YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_head.phtml

**add script:**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

> II.    gtm_body.phtml ---> YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml

**add nonscript:**

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

**after that open up**

> default .xml file: --->YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
>   and add this:

```
referenceContainer name="head.additional">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.head" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_head.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_body.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

After GTM is added you can set up Google Analytics and other scripts and test your implementation with google chrome plugin ([google tag assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=nl)).
If you have google analytics set already "old fashion" way through magento back-end
you have to remove it because you will end up double tracking your website 
and you will see 2 GA accounts on google tag tester.
Good Luck :)